# node throw err; TypeError: undefined is not a function ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nodejs

I have installed node v0.10.1 but now when I run bower install I got this error:

```
bower extracting /tmp/bower-bootstrap-233205yl5tjk/index.zip

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js:219
    throw err;
          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Until.PullStream._flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/unzip/node_modules/pullstream/pullstream.js:112:5)
    at Until.<anonymous> (_stream_transform.js:131:12)
    at Until.g (events.js:175:14)
    at Until.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:332:12)
    at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:339:3)
    at Until.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:326:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/unzip/lib/parse.js:282:25
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

so i did some googling and find out that i need to install node v0.8 instead of v0.10. how can I do that, because when I run this:

```
$ aptitude show node
Package: node
State: not installed
Version: 0.3.2-7.1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/hamradio
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: i386
Uncompressed Size: 299 k
Depends: libax25 (>= 0.0.11), libc6 (>= 2.7), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), update-inetd, openbsd-inetd | inet-superserver
Description: Amateur Packet Radio Node program
 The node program accepts TCP/IP and packet radio network connections and presents users with an interface that allows them to make gateway connections to remote hosts using a
```

and this:

```
$ aptitude show nodejs
Package: nodejs
State: installed
Automatically installed: yes
Version: 0.6.12~dfsg1-1ubuntu1
Priority: extra
Section: universe/web
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: i386
Uncompressed Size: 2,473 k
Depends: libc-ares2 (>= 1.7.3), libc6 (>= 2.6), libev4 (>= 1:4.04), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), libv8-3.7.12.22, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Conflicts: node
Description: Node.js event-based server-side javascript engine
 Node.js is similar in design to and influenced by systems like Ruby's Event Machine or Python's Twisted.

 It takes the event model a bit further - it presents the event loop as a language construct instead of as a library.

 Node.js is bundled with several useful libraries to handle server tasks : System, Events, Standard I/O, Modules, Timers, Child Processes, POSIX, HTTP, Multipart Parsing, TCP,
 DNS, Assert, Path, URL, Query Strings.
Homepage: http://nodejs.org/
```

So how can I install node v0.8.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having this problem, I end up installing nvm through:

```
npm install nvm
```

And then used nvm to install node v0.8:

```
nvm install v0.8.1
```

And that solved the problem for me.